# Can I use TypeScript instead of standard JS code in React/Angular frameworks?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Since TypeScript is a higher subset of JS, can I replace JS with TypeScript and use it with React or Angular or other JS framework?

Or do those frameworks only understand standard JS code?

Comment: It's a *super*set. It compiles to JS. Also Angular is written more or less exclusively in TS. I'd recommend some research.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can and this is highly recommended !

As @jonrsharpe pointed it out, TS compile to JS.

You can do some tests [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) in order to see how TS is working.